# Apply function with two inputs on every two last elements of array

Tags: function, numpy

Hi I have a 2d array looking this way

```
a = np.array[[12032, 12, 23, 12],[12032, 22, 12, 12]]
```

Where index 0 is ID, index 1 is x coordinate, index 2 is y coordinate and index 3 is z coordinate.

I have made a function that calculates the angle of the coordinate taking two inputs (length a, length b)

I want to apply this function with index 1 and 2 for each array element in the array and append the result in a new "column" in the array.

Comment: Could you explain the question?

Comment: I want to apply this function with index 1 and 2 for each array element in the array and append the result in a new "column" in the array.

Comment: `a[2:]` is a view with just the last columns.  What's your angle function?  Does it require scalar inputs, or will it work with 2 arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
angle = np.empty((0))
for array in elements_in_selection:
    nice = array
    a = array[1]
    b = array[2]
    angle_element = angle_calculate(a,b)
    angle = np.append(angle, np.array([angle_element]),axis=0)
angle = np.expand_dims(angle, axis=1)
elements_in_selection = np.append(elements_in_selection, angle, axis=1)
```

Comment: or `angle = np.array([ angle_calculate(row[1],row[2]) for row in elements_in_selection])[:,None]`.  List append or list comprehension is better than repeated `np.append`.